# How to paint colour using canvas on sticker view. I have Draw with a Canvas on a view, but nothing painted

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw, paint

I need to paint on image view but its type is sticker. Please help me for figure out the issue. Below file is `framelayout` which have `getMainView()` for sticker `imageview`. Below is link of my source code.

Please find below link of my whole source code for sticker. Which I want to paint.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XBJrEX62FsJ6dJXEbRQoPo29oQKClvy/view?usp=sharing

```
public abstract class StickerView extends FrameLayout{

public static final String TAG = "com.knef.stickerView";
private BorderView iv_border;
private ImageView iv_scale;
private ImageView iv_delete;
private ImageView iv_flip;
public Canvas canvasMaster;
public Path drawingPath;
float mX, mY;
public ArrayList<Path> paths;
Paint paint;
public int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
public float brushSize = 20.0f;

public Bitmap bitmapMaster;

// For scalling
private float this_orgX = -1, this_orgY = -1;
private float scale_orgX = -1, scale_orgY = -1;
private double scale_orgWidth = -1, scale_orgHeight = -1;
// For rotating
private float rotate_orgX = -1, rotate_orgY = -1, rotate_newX = -1, rotate_newY = -1;
// For moving
private float move_orgX =-1, move_orgY = -1;

private double centerX, centerY;

private final static int BUTTON_SIZE_DP = 30;
private final static int SELF_SIZE_DP = 100;



public StickerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    this.iv_border = new BorderView(context);
    this.iv_scale = new ImageView(context);
    this.iv_delete = new ImageView(context);
    this.iv_flip = new ImageView(context);

    paths = new ArrayList();
    paint = new Paint();

    this.iv_scale.setImageResource(R.drawable.sticker_resize);
    this.iv_delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.sticker_delete);
    this.iv_flip.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_change_size);

    this.setTag("erase");
   // this.setTag("DraggableViewGroup");
    this.iv_border.setTag("iv_border");
    this.iv_scale.setTag("iv_scale");
    this.iv_delete.setTag("iv_delete");
    this.iv_flip.setTag("iv_flip");

    int margin = convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext())/2;
    int size = convertDpToPixel(SELF_SIZE_DP, getContext());

    LayoutParams this_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    size,
                    size
            );
    this_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    LayoutParams iv_main_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
    iv_main_params.setMargins(margin,margin,margin,margin);

    LayoutParams iv_border_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
    iv_border_params.setMargins(margin,margin,margin,margin);

    LayoutParams iv_scale_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext()),
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext())
            );
    iv_scale_params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;

    LayoutParams iv_delete_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext()),
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext())
            );
    iv_delete_params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

    LayoutParams iv_flip_params =
            new LayoutParams(
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext()),
                    convertDpToPixel(BUTTON_SIZE_DP, getContext())
            );
    iv_flip_params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    this.setLayoutParams(this_params);
    this.addView(getMainView(), iv_main_params);
    this.addView(iv_border, iv_border_params);
    this.addView(iv_scale, iv_scale_params);
    this.addView(iv_delete, iv_delete_params);
    this.addView(iv_flip, iv_flip_params);
    this.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    this.iv_scale.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    this.iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(StickerView.this.getParent()!=null){
                ViewGroup myCanvas = ((ViewGroup)StickerView.this.getParent());
                myCanvas.removeView(StickerView.this);
            }
        }
    });
    this.iv_flip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "flip the view");

            View mainView = getMainView();
            mainView.setRotationY(mainView.getRotationY() == -180f? 0f: -180f);
            mainView.invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }
    });
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    canvasMaster = new Canvas();
    drawingPath = new Path();
    paths.add(drawingPath);
}

public boolean isFlip(){
    return getMainView().getRotationY() == -180f;
}


private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    drawingPath.reset();
    drawingPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}


public void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    try {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            drawingPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;


            int pixel = 0;

            //then do what you want with the pixel data, e.g
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            alpha=(alpha / 100) * 60;
         //   paint.setARGB( 50, redValue, greenValue, blueValue);


            drawPath();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //  mTouchPath.reset();

}

private void drawPath() {


    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) brushSize);
    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(60);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setMaskFilter(null);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawingPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    canvasMaster.drawPath(drawingPath, paint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    //   mTouchPath.reset();
    drawingPath.reset();
    drawingPath.moveTo(mX, mY);

    View mainView = getMainView();
    mainView.invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}


private void touch_up() {

    drawPath();
  /*  setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    realBitmaps = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
   setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    bitmaps.add(realBitmaps);*/

}


protected abstract ImageView getMainView();

private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if(view.getTag().equals("erase")) {
          float  x = event.getX();
          float  y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    //get sticker
                    getMainView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    bitmapMaster = getMainView().getDrawingCache();
                    canvasMaster.drawBitmap(bitmapMaster, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
                    getMainView().setImageBitmap(bitmapMaster);

                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    getMainView().setImageBitmap(bitmapMaster);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }else
        if(view.getTag().equals("DraggableViewGroup")) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action down");
                    move_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    move_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action move");
                    float offsetX = event.getRawX() - move_orgX;
                    float offsetY = event.getRawY() - move_orgY;
                    StickerView.this.setX(StickerView.this.getX()+offsetX);
                    StickerView.this.setY(StickerView.this.getY() + offsetY);
                    move_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    move_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action up");
                    break;
            }
        }else if(view.getTag().equals("iv_scale")){
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action down");

                    this_orgX = StickerView.this.getX();
                    this_orgY = StickerView.this.getY();

                    scale_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    scale_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    scale_orgWidth = StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width;
                    scale_orgHeight = StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height;

                    rotate_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    rotate_orgY = event.getRawY();

                    centerX = StickerView.this.getX()+
                            ((View)StickerView.this.getParent()).getX()+
                            (float)StickerView.this.getWidth()/2;


                    //double statusBarHeight = Math.ceil(25 * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                    int result = 0;
                    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                    if (resourceId > 0) {
                        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                    }
                    double statusBarHeight = result;
                    centerY = StickerView.this.getY()+
                            ((View)StickerView.this.getParent()).getY()+
                            statusBarHeight+
                            (float)StickerView.this.getHeight()/2;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action move");

                    rotate_newX = event.getRawX();
                    rotate_newY = event.getRawY();

                    double angle_diff = Math.abs(
                            Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY , event.getRawX() - scale_orgX)
                                    - Math.atan2(scale_orgY - centerY, scale_orgX - centerX))*180/Math.PI;

                    Log.v(TAG, "angle_diff: "+angle_diff);

                    double length1 = getLength(centerX, centerY, scale_orgX, scale_orgY);
                    double length2 = getLength(centerX, centerY, event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());

                    int size = convertDpToPixel(SELF_SIZE_DP, getContext());
                    if(length2 > length1
                            && (angle_diff < 25 || Math.abs(angle_diff-180)<25)
                            ) {
                        //scale up
                        double offsetX = Math.abs(event.getRawX() - scale_orgX);
                        double offsetY = Math.abs(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY);
                        double offset = Math.max(offsetX, offsetY);
                        offset = Math.round(offset);
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width += offset;
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height += offset;
                        onScaling(true);
                        //DraggableViewGroup.this.setX((float) (getX() - offset / 2));
                        //DraggableViewGroup.this.setY((float) (getY() - offset / 2));
                    }else if(length2 < length1
                            && (angle_diff < 25 || Math.abs(angle_diff-180)<25)
                            && StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width > size/2
                            && StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height > size/2) {
                        //scale down
                        double offsetX = Math.abs(event.getRawX() - scale_orgX);
                        double offsetY = Math.abs(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY);
                        double offset = Math.max(offsetX, offsetY);
                        offset = Math.round(offset);
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width -= offset;
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height -= offset;
                        onScaling(false);
                    }

                    //rotate

                    double angle = Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - centerY, event.getRawX() - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI;
                    Log.v(TAG, "log angle: " + angle);

                    //setRotation((float) angle - 45);
                    setRotation((float) angle - 45);
                    Log.v(TAG, "getRotation(): " + getRotation());

                    onRotating();

                    rotate_orgX = rotate_newX;
                    rotate_orgY = rotate_newY;

                    scale_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    scale_orgY = event.getRawY();

                    postInvalidate();
                    requestLayout();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action up");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};


private double getLength(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2-y1, 2)+Math.pow(x2-x1, 2));
}

private float[] getRelativePos(float absX, float absY){
    Log.v("ken", "getRelativePos getX:"+((View)this.getParent()).getX());
    Log.v("ken", "getRelativePos getY:"+((View)this.getParent()).getY());
    float [] pos = new float[]{
            absX-((View)this.getParent()).getX(),
            absY-((View)this.getParent()).getY()
    };
    Log.v(TAG, "getRelativePos absY:"+absY);
    Log.v(TAG, "getRelativePos relativeY:"+pos[1]);
    return pos;
}

public void setControlItemsHidden(boolean isHidden){
    if(isHidden) {
        iv_border.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_scale.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_flip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        iv_border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_scale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_flip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

protected View getImageViewFlip(){
    return iv_flip;
}

protected void onScaling(boolean scaleUp){}

protected void onRotating(){}

private class BorderView extends View{

    public BorderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BorderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BorderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Draw sticker border

        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();

        Log.v(TAG,"params.leftMargin: "+params.leftMargin);

        Rect border = new Rect();
        border.left = (int)this.getLeft()-params.leftMargin;
        border.top = (int)this.getTop()-params.topMargin;
        border.right = (int)this.getRight()-params.rightMargin;
        border.bottom = (int)this.getBottom()-params.bottomMargin;
        Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        borderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(border, borderPaint);

    }
}

private static int convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int)px;
}

public void setControlsVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    if(!isVisible) {
        iv_border.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv_flip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv_scale.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        iv_border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_flip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_scale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is with layout params try  drawing a hardcoded rectangle, like `border.left = 50`, `border.right = 30`

Comment: canvas has size, so use it

Comment: @Style-7 : whats your mean please help me please get my code from below link and post me solution I am stuck from 7 days.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan : I am using getmainview() its my image view. border is different thing.

Comment: Try to set Rect border by canvas.getWidth getHeight